# C# Cast Exception

Tags: c#, performance, exception

Stumbled on some old code that is throwing and empty catching some cast exceptions (about 20 per trip :( )

What if any is the performance hit were taking due to this? Should I be worried about this or is the overhead simply in the try / catch

Surprisingly lacking information on the topic of exception performance with C#.

Thanks, from yours truly.

Comment: Ended up finding a problem with the essence of the method itself and turned a 30 line monster of explicit casts to try catchs, into two lines of code that went from 3.8 seconds with 10000 items down to 3 milliseconds. 
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exceptions are going to slow you down more than most average lines of code.  Instead of casting and then catching the exception, do a check instead.  For example

**BAD**

```
myType foo = (myType)obj;
foo.ExecuteOperation();
```

**GOOD**

```
myType foo = obj as myType;
if (foo != null)
{
     foo.ExecuteOperation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's bad for two reasons.

1. Exceptions are slow, there is quite a performance hit. I don't think it'd take an entire millisecond as Matt pointed out, but they are slow enough that you want to avoid them in normal operation.
2. Unless you have a good reason, you shouldn't catch empty exceptions. You're just hiding problems. Better that a program crashes than that it carries on with potentially dangerous bugs.

If they're just `try { } finally { }` groups, then it's all good -- there's no overhead there. However, `try { } catch { }` is both potentially dangerous and potentially slow.

As for documentation, this is pretty good: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx#Don%27tuseexceptionhandlingasmeansofreturninginformationfromamethod18

Edit: just realized you said *empty catching* exceptions, not *catching empty* exceptions. Either way, unless you're dealing with IO, you probably want to avoid doing that for performance's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are expensive, performance-wise.  Last time I measured these, they were taking **about a full millisecond** to throw and catch each exception.

Avoid using exceptions as a flow control mechanism.

Comment: Shouldn't he handle the exception, just not by throwing an exception, he could handle it gracefully.  Any exception he cannot gracefully catch is the type of exception you want thrown if it happen, they shouldn't happen of course if he is careful.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Exceptions are expensive when thrown. In some cases they can't be avoided.

In this case, though, it sounds like they definitely can be.

I would suggest using a the the `as` keyword before the cast. That will tell you if the cast succeeded or not thus avoiding the Exception altogether:

```
object someObject;
SomeType typedObject;

// fill someObject

typedObject = someObject as SomeType;

if(typedObject == null)
{
    // Cast failed
}
```

Comment: One should either combine `if(x is T) y = (T)x;` or `y = x as T; if(x != null)`. The former also works with structs.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't encountered any performance problem and this is the only way you have to do that algorithm continue to use this method.

Maybe before trying to cast you could see with some `if` clauses if you could do the cast.

Comment: Exceptions are expensive. It's bad practice to use them for normal operation.

Comment: I have never said that they're not expensive. If you read my post I've written that he can use it only if he don't catch performance problems or if it is the only way to write the algorithm.

Comment: The operative expression here is "if...this is the only way you have to do that algorithm." Sometimes, you have to break the rules. It's not ugly, but it's the truth. Though I'd probably refactor such code to use TryParse, the question still remains: what do you do if it fails?

Comment: If for instance you're writing a program to parse a large amount data, some of which might be integers, using `int.Parse` will cause a new Exception object to be created, containing an unwinding of the entire stack. Meanwhile, `int.TryParse` will take little more than a few clock cycles. Also, I honestly can't come up with an example of an algorithm that requires exceptions to be used in normal operation. If this weren't normal operation that he's asking about, then I doubt he would have asked the question in the first place -- because clearly exceptional operation is what exceptions are for.

Comment: There's a non-insignificant number of third-party libraries that internally do a lot of "flow control exceptions".  How to check for file existance?  Open the file and see if it fails!  In this case, checking for the file's existence directly doesn't help much, as it may cease to exist just before you use it anyway, but after your check.  So there are circumstances where exceptions are expected, and used as a flow-control mechanism.